# How do you use a custom comparator for priority queues?

Tags: java, queue, comparator

I'm trying to implement a priority queue that compares Nodes that have a "cost" value. I have tried 3 implementations of comparators and none of them have worked.

Node def:

```java
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    int[][] data;
    int x, y;
    int cost;
    Node parent;
    Node (int[][] data, int x, int y, int newX, int newY, Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
            
        //SWAPS VALUE
        int temp = data[newX][newY];
        data[newX][newY] = data[x][y];
        data[x][y] = temp;
            
        this.cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            
        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
    }
        
    public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
        if (this.cost < otherNode.cost) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.cost > otherNode.cost) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

First Comparator:

```
Comparator<Node> CustomComp = new Comparator<Node>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node lhs, Node rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
};
```

Second Comparator:

```
Comparator<Node> CustomComp2 = (Node lhs, Node rhs) -> {
    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
};
```

Third Comparator:

```
public class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node lhs, Node rhs) {
        if (lhs.cost < rhs.cost) {
            return -1;
        } else if (lhs.cost > rhs.cost) {
                return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Priority Queue Implementation:

```java
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(11, comp);
```

*this implementation was after attempting to use the last one*

This is also my first question here, and thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This is the error it gives for `new PriorityQueue<Node>(11, comp)`

The constructor PriorityQueue<main.Node>(int, main.Comparator<main.Node>) is undefined

There is no output currently but it should store nodes for later use in a tree.

Comment: all your comparators look fine to me (in fact i think they all do the same thing and no comparator is need since Node implements Comparable). However if cost is always Integer.MAX_VALUE everything will return 0

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them have worked."? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs, and explain how the actual output of your program differs from the desired output?

Comment: Should not `cost` value be set in a different way to have different values in different `Node` instances?  Then comparator by cost might look like `Comparator.comparingInt(node -> node.cost)` or (if a getter exists) `Comparator.comparingInt(Node::getCost)`

Comment: @Andi the value is there temporarily just so that if it doesnt get assigned a value it would end up at the back of the queue

Comment: the error message in your edit seems to suggest that comp is an instance of main.Comparator (a class or instance in your code) and not an instance of java.util.Comparator (which is required). I suggest changing the name of your local Comparator class/interface

Comment: @Andi what do you suggest I change it too?

Comment: anything that is different from Comparator like Comparator2 or MyComparator